# How to load only a part of file by useing FileReference.load in Flash

Tags: actionscript

Is there any way to load only a part of a big file by useing FileReference.load() in flash player?

It's known that the AS3 API FileReference has given the ability to load local file in flash.
However, in the case which you want pre-process this file in flash, the only way is by using the FileReference.load function. Unfortunately, the FileReference.load function will load the total file in the memory immediately. And the size of the loading file is limited up to 100M.

So, what i want to do is just load a part of the file whoes size is under 100M, process it, and upload it, and then load another one.

Any one has any idea?

Thanks :)

Comment: Check URLStream class, it might be what you are looking for.
_Data is made available to application code immediately as it is downloaded, instead of waiting until the entire file is complete as with URLLoader._

Comment: Thanks for your replay.But the URLStream is not the point. What i want to do is to use FileReference to load a "LOCAL" File, and then process it. The FileReference.load function will fullfill the variable FileReference.data, which will take over too much memory. So I want to find a way to load the big file into memory partaclly.